# How sparksql can batch insert data to mysql?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

All.
Recently I need to insert about 100,000,000 data into mysql by using sparksql, however the speed is quite low, it takes about 1 hour. Can some one have a efficent way to insert ?

mysql configuration =>

```
prop.setProperty("user", "user")
prop.setProperty("password", "password")
prop.setProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true")
prop.setProperty("batchsize", "1000000")
prop.setProperty("numPartitions", "3000")
```

Comment: Why don't you write that data into MySQL on your own? If that is fixed data, create a proper dump to be imported

Comment: Because I think spark already provide this insert function, it should be have a efficient way.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your MySQL URI. Your URI would be something like it: `jdbc:mysql://host:port/db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

Hope it helps.

### Update

Try it, it worked for me. Setting the `driver` property did the trick.

```
val prop = new Properties()

prop.setProperty("user", dbUser)
prop.setProperty("password", dbPassword)
prop.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

df.write.mode("append").jdbc("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + "/" + dbName + "?rewriteBatchedStatements=true", "TABLE_NAME", prop)
```

And also I had to import the Java MySQL connector.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @whathaha I updated my answer.  I tried it and it worked for me. Please tell me if it also worked for you

Comment: I'm so glad!! Can you please vote up my answer and accept it? :) @whathaha